# Member from group with edit permissions can't add/edit items, other users from same group can

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups

I have this weird thing where sometimes, a user contacts me to say they can no longer add or edit items from a document library or list. When I check the groups that have edit permissions on those lists or libraries, the user usually is a member of that group.
So I have a user X, who is member of group Y. Group Y has edit and read permissions on list Z. All other users of group Y can add or edit items from list Z. But user X can't.
What causes this? And even weirder, if I remove user X from group Y, then add user X to group Y again, user X all of a sudden can add or edit items from list Z. Why couldn't user X do so before? Is there a known bug or issue or anything else known about this? It's something that I occasionally see, roughly once every two months or so, but it's been going on for over a year now and I'd like to know why this is. 
 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Magali,

This very same problem happened to us not too long ago...and I was pulling my hair out for days. It may not apply in your case, but some of our user AD accounts were recreated for some reason. Even though their user name stayed the same, the SID is different when you recreate and account. We had to do exactly what you mentioned. We had to delete the user from the group and add them back for the new SID to take.

Check with your AD administrator and see if this has been happening.

P.S. Congrats on living in an amazing area...once drove from Heidelberg to Ghent just to fill up a car with Tripel Karmeliet. Good times...